# Path/file access error with LoadPicture, seems based on path length

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a userform which lets users select a template slide to insert. When they are selecting a slide, a preview image is shown, using LoadPicture.
We are using a OneDrive synchronised folder, so everybody has the same slides.

Some people are getting errors on some slides, which seems based on file path lengths. For me, any filename over 126 characters is giving an error. Other collegues have longer paths, but are getting no errors.

The image files all exist, and I can't find any other difference. Any clues on why this is happening, and on how to solve this?

[image: Example of the error. The first selected slide works, the second does not]

Corresponding debug lines:

```
126 - C:\<redacted>\Business - AMG - Templates\01. Powerpoint\images\img_4-IP-ffp\Business activities IT services.jpg
129 - C:\<redacted>\Business - AMG - Templates\01. Powerpoint\images\img_4-IP-ffp\Business solution generieke aanpak.jpg
```

Code:

```vb
Private Sub lb_slides_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If lb_slides <> "" Then
        Slide = strPath & strLocImage & strCatSlide & "\" & lb_slides.Column(1) & ".jpg"
        Debug.Print Len(Slide) & " - " & Slide
        tb_slide.Picture = LoadPicture(Slide)

        selected_slide = lb_slides.Column(0)
    End If

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox err.Description & "  " & err.HelpContext, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "lb_slides"
End Sub
```

Comment: which version of powerpoint are you using

Comment: PowerPoint for Office 365, version 1907. I think that's the 2016 version.

Comment: According to MS do, The total length of both the path and the file name, including file name extension can not exceeds 256 characters. So i think that it's not a problem of length ..

Comment: I would also assume that, but making a folder name shorter did result in more images working

Comment: put image on your desktop and rename to make the path have a 163char size then see what happen

Comment: Tried on my desktop with a full path of 247 characters. I'm getting the same error every time.
Also tried other lengths. Everything over 126 characters crashes. Everything 126 or below works

Comment: Try with 200 char ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197716/discussion-between-jackstones-and-dorian).

Comment: @JackStoneS .. Did you try the below answer??

Comment: I'll try this tonight

Answer (score 0):

*Though I am not able to Reproduce the Error*. But this may work.

Let me know if it doesn't work, I ll remove the Answer.

If the length of the path is the issue, maybe you can change the Working Directory to the folder all of your images are in, using `ChDir` and then after the code change it once again to the old folder.

That ways you don't have to Pass the lengthy path to the `LoadPicture`.

```
Private Sub lb_slides_Click()

Dim old As String
Dim nw As String

old = CurDir

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If lb_slides <> "" Then

        nw = strPath & strLocImage & strCatSlide
        ChDir nw

        Slide = lb_slides.Column(1) & ".jpg"
        Debug.Print Len(Slide) & " - " & Slide
        tb_slide.Picture = LoadPicture(Slide)

        selected_slide = lb_slides.Column(0)

        ChDir old

    End If

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description & "  " & Err.HelpContext, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "lb_slides"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to this earlier. I've tried your approach, but unfortunately that doesn't solve the error. I'll look into other possibilities